# `git stash -p` showing files in lfs

Tags: git, git-stash, git-lfs

I have a repository that uses git-lfs, and the files in lfs are committed.  However, when I use `git stash -p`, git asks me if I want to stash each and every file in lfs.  How do I skip these files in the questions?  If I stash everything and `git stash show`, it does not show the lfs files as stashed.  It seems to be an issue specific to `-p`.

git version 2.17.1

git-lfs/2.3.4 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.8.3)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I worked around it:

```
 git stash # stash everything
 git stash apply # apply the stash, but keep it in the stash (don't pop)
 git checkout to_keep # discard the stuff you want to keep in your working tree (remember it's in the stash)
 git stash save "message" # stash the stuff you want to stash
 git stash pop stash@{1} # apply the first stash, which includes the stuff you wanted to keep and the stuff you wanted to stash
 git checkout to_stash # discard the stuff you stashed
```

Answer (score -2):

What about using feature branches and avoiding using the stash completely?

Comment: this work is being abandoned and we already have lots of abandoned branches.  though you do ask a good question.  maybe we should rename our abandoned branches...

Comment: To the person who -1 in 2022. I'm sorry the answer was not what you're looking for. I wished you commented on why you think this is a answer.

Comment: if you click the -1, you can see 2 people gave -1 (though maybe you are referring to the latest vote which i cannot see when that happened)